# how to get field value in logstash?

Tags: logstash

from my output  as below,

> "message" =>"<....... ",
>   
>  "@version" => "1",
>   
> "@timestamp" => "2016-04-29T02:33:34.586Z",
>   
> "timestamp" => "Apr 29 10:30:37",
>   
> "syslog_severity_code" => 5,
>   
> "syslog_facility_code" => 1,
>   
> "syslog_facility" => "user-level",
>   
> "syslog_severity" => "notice"

i try to get the field value

```
filter
 {
    mutate {
    add_field => {"newfield"=> "timestamp"}
 }
```

but still cann't get the timestamp value to newfield
it's will get

```
"newfield" => "newfield",
```

Is anyone is having the same problem or find a solution?
Any help is welcome to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That`s easy,do it like this:

```
filter
 {
   mutate {
    add_field => ["newfield"=> "%{timestamp}"]
 }
```

You can get :

```
   "message" => "test it \b\b",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-04-28T09:16:56.934Z",
      "host" => "bag",
 "timestamp" => "Apr 29 10:30:37",
 "new_field" => "Apr 29 10:30:37"
```